# Remote work and employer monitoring

Tags: privacy, vpn, monitoring

My work laptop is connected to my router via ethernet and personal laptop is connected via wifi to same router. Whenever I switch my vpn on on my personal computer, the connection icon becomes that of the ethernet connection (but has no hardline connection). Is there crossover somehow and my activity is able to be seen by my employer even on my personal laptop w a vpn running?

Comment: No. It's an ethernet icon because Windows doesn't have a specific icon for a VPN, not because it's actually using ethernet.

Comment: As I told you before, your answers are on the thread you've already seen.

Answer (score 1):

No, your employer won't be able to see what you're doing on your personal network.

When you mount the VPN on your personal laptop, your network connection icon change to the same "wired network" icon. I believe this is because your VPN client emulates a physical adapter, and the Windows OS doesn't make the difference with a wired connection.

I couldn't find a source from Microsoft explaining why it was built this way and whether this is considered an expected behavior.

Comment: Ok. The ethernet icon didn’t begin appearing on my personal laptop until I after had connected the ethernet cord to my work laptop so I was a bit iffy. Thank you for your answer.